# Intel SGX Running Executable on Remote Machine

Tags: sgx

I have been porting some code to SGX, in Linux, which I would like to run on a remote server in the end.
I observed that if I build the program and then use the same executable to run the program inside SGX on a different machine, different from the one on which the program was built using SGX SDK, the code still runs without any issues.

Now, if I look into the MRENCLAVE value during the build, I observe that the value is different if I build the same code on different machines. If I ship an executable build on machine A to machine B and do not build it again on machine B, then the MRENCLAVE value is the one which I got from building it on machine A. The question is that this value is different if I build the code on machine B itself. Does this not cause any issues if I want to do attestation of the code on machine B but do not want to rebuild project on machine B and instead use the build from machine A?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know is the MRENCLAVE measurement dependent on the used tool chain (cf. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bc12/7b2228219f2b36b66bebe71a844e510e8efe.pdf, Sections 5.6.3 and 5.6.4) since it is indirectly a hash over the assembly instructions and created by explicit assembly instructions during enclave creation (EEXTEND). Thus, I would expect that you, at least, use different compiler versions on the mentioned machines?